# How do I go to the next command in Git Bash after using git log?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-log

When using Git Bash, I type the command:

```
git log
```

It shows me all the logs. But now I want to do a second command. So I hold the down arrow to get to the bottom of the logs and it just says `(END)`. How do I get to the next line so I can enter my next command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, Git commands that display a lot of information will show the information through a different program, called [terminal pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager). These programs basically show you the information in pages, so that you can see everything and not only the very last bit of information at the end.

The most known pagers include [`more`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)) and [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)).

Git for Windows comes bundled with `less` and is configured to use that by default. Less gives you the ability to scroll up and down the output (using your arrow keys), so you can browse for as long as you want. In order **to exist the program, you need to press the <kbd>q</kbd> key** on your keyboard. This will put you back into bash.

You can change the paging behavior of Git by configuring the [`core.pager` configuration](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Answer (score 2):

Git by default will page to less.

Less can be quit by pressing <kbd>q</kbd> or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

to quit form the git log you need to type <kbd>q</kbd>.

If you want to "limit" the log entries :

```
# display only the first X entries form the log.
# This way you will not have the pager so mo need to quit from the pager
git log -n <number of commits>
```

If you want to run multiple commands use the &&:

```
git log -n 10 && git status
```

---

### ***`--no-pager`***

`--no-pager` will disable the pager got the given command.

```
git --no-pager log  ...
git --no-pager diff ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `B` and `F` for backward/forward navigation in git bash results.

Also using the `Space` on the keyboard also works for the forward movement.

You can quit the resuls and get back to promp, using `Q` .